# Dart While Loop usage

Tags: dart

i have a logic mistake but i cant figure out, loop not stops when num= returnitemcount ?

```
void main() {
  List<int> listAll = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  List<int> exceptions = [2, 3, 4];
  List<int> exceptedlist(
      int returnitemcount, List<int> exceptions, List<int> listfrom) {
    List<int> returnlist = [];
    int num = 0;
    while (num < returnitemcount) {
      for (var i = 0; i < listfrom.length; i++) {
        if (!exceptions.contains(listfrom[i])) {
          returnlist.add(listfrom[i]);
          num++;
        }
      }
    }
    return returnlist;
  }

  List<int> mylist = exceptedlist(3, exceptions, listAll);
  print(mylist);
  // expected => 1,5,6
  // result => 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
}
```

Comment: You need to step through the code in the debugger, examine variable values to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `while` are only evaluated twice. The first time `num` is `0` and the second time it is `6`. It is not evaluated every time `num` is updated.

`while` loops does not mean that the code inside the block are running as long some statement are true. It means the code will loop as long the statement are true.

So what you need to do is to check `num` every time you update the value. Something like this:

```
void main() {
  List<int> listAll = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  List<int> exceptions = [2, 3, 4];
  List<int> exceptedlist(
      int returnitemcount, List<int> exceptions, List<int> listfrom) {
    List<int> returnlist = [];
    int num = 0;
    while (num < returnitemcount) {
      for (var i = 0; i < listfrom.length; i++) {
        if (!exceptions.contains(listfrom[i])) {
          returnlist.add(listfrom[i]);
          if (++num >= returnitemcount) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return returnlist;
  }

  List<int> mylist = exceptedlist(3, exceptions, listAll);
  print(mylist); // [1, 5, 6]
}
```

I am not sure what you code are going to do exactly but you should be able to skip the `while` loop:

```
void main() {
  List<int> listAll = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  List<int> exceptions = [2, 3, 4];
  List<int> exceptedlist(
      int returnitemcount, List<int> exceptions, List<int> listfrom) {
    List<int> returnlist = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < listfrom.length; i++) {
      if (!exceptions.contains(listfrom[i])) {
        returnlist.add(listfrom[i]);
        if (returnlist.length >= returnitemcount) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return returnlist;
  }

  List<int> mylist = exceptedlist(3, exceptions, listAll);
  print(mylist); // [1, 5, 6]
}
```

And can properly even be shorten into:

```
void main() {
  final listAll = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  final exceptions = [2, 3, 4];

  final mylist = exceptedlist(3, exceptions, listAll);
  print(mylist); // [1, 5, 6]
}

List<int> exceptedlist(
        int returnitemcount, List<int> exceptions, List<int> listfrom) =>
    listfrom
        .where((element) => !exceptions.contains(element))
        .take(returnitemcount)
        .toList();
```

Comment: thanks so much, the second one is that i want 
edit:omg! 3rd one is awesome you know this job dude!